# Password encryption Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, encryption, hash, password-encryption

Currently I'm working on a project where I made a registration form which is connected to a MySQL database. The project is written in Python with Flask.

I have figured out how send information to the DB, and how to hash the passwords chosen on the registerpage. However, I'm struggling to find out how to log in with an account with an hashed password.

If I try to log in with an account with a hashed password, I first need to login with the unhashed password, which is then hashed, and compared to the hashed password in the database. 
But this doesn't work.

From my understanding, this is where you find the username and password, which are filled out on the login page:

```
username = request.form['username']
password = request.form['password']
```

So, after this step you should encrypt it to match the hashed password in the DB:

```
password = b'password'

hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
```

Then, you should compare it:

```
if bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed_password):
    print("It matches!")
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
else:
    print("Didn't match")
```

But this is not working. I can't log in with the given password, only with a hashed password. Where is the mistake made in the encryption? Full snippet code:

```
def login():
# Output message if something goes wrong...
msg = ''

# Check if "username" and "password" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
    # Create variables for easy access
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']

    password = b'password'

    hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())

    # Check if account exists using MySQL
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password = %s', (username, hashed_password))
    # Fetch one record and return result
    account = cursor.fetchone()
    # If account exists in accounts table in our database
    if account:
        # Create session data, we can access this data in other routes
        session['loggedin'] = True
        session['id'] = account['id']
        session['username'] = account['username']
        # Redirect to home page
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        # Account doesnt exist or username/password incorrect
        msg = 'Incorrect username/password!'
# Show the login form with message (if any)
return render_template('index.html', msg=msg)
```

Comment: In the snippet above, you're not using the password from the HTML form, but overwriting it with the bytestring `b'password'`. You probably want to do `password = password.encode('utf-8')`. Otherwise you're correct, you need to compare the hashed password with the one supplied via the HTML form. Your use of checkpw is fine.

Comment: I removed the password=  b'password', however now I cannot log in at all...

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Perform these steps in order. 1) Retrieve the bcrypt hashed password from database, 2) compare it with user-supplied password for the login using `bcrypt.checkpw()`. `bcrypt.hashpw()` is only used when the password is created, or changed. It's strange that you mention `checkpw()` at the beginning of your question but then don't use it at all in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MySQL, I would suggest you rather use md5 to verify the user from the table in the database.
Change the following code:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password = md5(%s)', (username, hashed_password))
```

and to convert all the unencrypted plain texts password run following query:

```
UPDATE accounts SET password = MD5(password);
```